# Magento 2.1.7, 2.2.3 : wrong placeholder image url

Tags: magento2, url, media, media-images

I try created new product without image after that view in frontend the image url not true. I inspect element the url of image not true. 
`.../media/product/placeholder/default/image.jpg` lost **catalog**
the url true must be:
`.../media/catalog/product/placeholder/default/image.jpg`.

**Edit**
I checked: 
- admin placeholder url is: `../media/catalog/product...`
- frontend placeholder url is: `../media/product...`
I don't understand why has difference in both.

I tried reindex and flush media cache but not change. please help me resolve this issue. Many thanks!

Comment: To resolve this issue you just need to add a placeholder image on /media/product/placeholder/default/image.jpg

Comment: it I try it but it not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

- On the Admin sidebar go to `Stores > Settings > Configuration.`
- In the panel, under `Catalog`, choose `Catalog`.
- Expand the `Product Image Placeholders` section.